# Can't add widgets to home screen on Huawei P30 Pro

Tags: huawei, app-widgets

I have a Huawei P30 Pro on Android 12. I normally have a large clock on my home screen, but it was somehow removed and I can't add it back.

I click/tap and hold and I don't get any options to add a widget or anything for the fact. I've searched and all articles say to tap and hold to add a widget, but nothing appears to me.

How to add a widget to the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select a screen where you want to add your (lost) widget.
2. **Pinch with 2 fingers** (move them as you would to zoom this screen out).
   In the bottom of your screen will appear some icons.
3. Tap on the **Widget** icon. The bottom row of icon will change to (scrollable) row of icons of your widgets.
4. Select your lost widget.

[This instructing video](https://youtu.be/25wSuBIOvX0) may help you, too.